# Webpack 4 SplitChunksPlugin: Split vendor per entry

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to build two entries with Webpack 4. Some packages in node_modules and some parts of code are used in both entries. I need to separate vendor chunk from both entries. Example:

- admin.js, vendor-admin.js (both kind of big, because of many used packages)
- client.js, vendor-client.js (small, used on public websites)

I have tried following webpack configuration:

```
entry: {
  admin: 'src/admin/main.js',
  client: 'src/client/main.js'
},
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      'vendor-admin': {
        name: 'vendor-admin',
        chunks: chunk => chunk.name === 'admin',
      },
      'vendor-client': {
        name: 'client-vendor-client',
        chunks: chunk => chunk.name === 'client',
      },
    }
  }
},
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Client works ok, but admin crashes on unknown variable. Without splitting everything works just ok.

Comment: I'm looking to do this exact thing as well and can't figure it out. @PlayMa256 that would create a single vendor file with code for both the admin and the client in one, which is what they are trying to avoid.